# UIMA RUTA - How To Process Words In A Particular Order?

Tags: java, uima, ruta

I have written a UIMA annotation engine in Java and I want to move the rules out of Java into RUTA.  One of the things my Java engine does is process the words and apply rules in a particular order which is a different order to the words in the sentence.

Using an example sentence "The system requests a username and password." would not be processed in that order.  Instead my rules are applied based on the structure of the Dependency annotations, so the sentence is instead processed in this order [requests, The, system, username, ., a, and, password]

I was therefore wondering if there is an easy way to apply RUTA rules in a different order, without reordering the CAS, perhaps using an index?  I could continue to use Java to create an index annotation like this: The(2) system(3) requests(1) a(6) username(4) and(7) password(8).(5) but I can't figure out how to use the forEach BLOCK or some other RUTA logic to process these in the index order.

If you are wondering why I need to process them in order, the reason is that the application of my rules requires the Dependency hierarchy.  The annotation of the dependent is driven by the annotation of the governor/parent.

Comment: Don't think of RUTA as a system that processes words (in order) ; it deals with rules and annotations. Yes, the rules are evaluated in order and annotations are matched in order. But annotations can have features that are themselves annotation, and you can write (taking a grammatical analogy) a rule that looks like "mark any verb `v` whose subject feature `v.subject` matches the regexp `XX` as `YY`". So your bet would be to translate your dep tree into annotation features, and write rules according to this translation. The order may not then play such a role.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the depth of the annotations because I have already built a java annotation engine.  Words was just a simple way of describing my dilemma.   Whether words or annotations I cannot process this in the order in which they stream.  I have to change that order because my logic depends on it.  I have to know the annotation covering the word "requests" in order to set an appropriate annotation covering the word "system".  Since system comes before requests in the sentence I cannot create an annotation on system first because at that point its governor will have no annotation.

Comment: Actually GPI you may have given me an idea.  I'll go and experiment a little but if anybody else has experience in this area I would really appreciate hearing your thoughts.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem? If yes, can you share your solution? If not, you use case probably needs to be approached in a different manor. You maybe do not need to represent the dependencies in a sequential order, maybe conjunctions of feature checks are sufficient.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution.  I reverted to writing my own java code using UIMA/UIMAFit to read and order the words/annotations in the sentence.  I tried to think of other ways to solve my problem but in the end I always came back to ordered processing as the simple answer.

Comment: I found a solution @PeterKluegl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of doing this using blocks.  Since blocks can be recursive, I create a child block first, which looks up the items parent, and then calls the parent block.  For example using the dependency structure I can annotate the governor before the dependent (with special logic when you get to the ROOT).

```
d:dep.Dependency{d.DependencyType!="ROOT"}->{
    d.Governor{-IS(MyItem)}->{
        CALL(myPackage.AnnotateGovernor);
    };
};
```